# Numbers of distinct products obtained by permuting the factors

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is it true that for every $k \in \{1, \dots, n!\}$ there are
some group $G$ and pairwise distinct elements $g_1, \dots, g_n \in G$ such that the set
$\{g_{\sigma(1)} \cdot \ \dots \ \cdot g_{\sigma(n)} \ | \ \sigma \in {\rm S}_n\}$
of all products of the $g_i$ obtained by permuting the factors has cardinality $k$?

**Added on Mar 21, 2013:** On Mar 19, 2013, Benjamin Young gave a presentation of
a group in which the above set has cardinality $\leq k$ (see below). As such this is
trivial, since this is the case in particular in every abelian group. The thing that
is missing to turn this into an answer to the question is to prove that the given
relations do not force equality among any other products.

The assertion is true at least for $n \leq 4$.
In case $n = 4$, for all $k \in \{1, \dots, 4!\}$ suitable 4-tuples of group elements
can be taken from ${\rm S}_5$:

```
k =  1: (), (1,2), (3,4), (1,2)(3,4)              [    215]
k =  2: (), (1,2)(3,4), (1,2,3,4), (2,4)          [   1845]
k =  3: (), (2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4)                 [  10230]
k =  4: (), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)                   [  38870]
k =  5: (), (1,2), (2,3), (2,3,4)                 [  85350]
k =  6: (), (1,2), (2,3), (2,4)                   [ 186220]
k =  7: (1,2), (1,2,3,4), (2,3,4), (2,4,3)        [   7920]
k =  8: (1,2), (2,3), (2,3,4), (2,4,3)            [  40560]
k =  9: (1,2), (2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4)              [  39535]
k = 10: (1,2), (1,2)(3,4), (2,3), (2,3,4),        [  96240]
k = 11: (1,2), (1,2)(3,4), (2,3), (2,4)           [ 116715]
k = 12: (1,2), (1,2,3), (2,4,3), (2,4)            [ 264360]
k = 13: (1,2), (1,2,3), (1,5), (2,3,4)            [ 284020]
k = 14: (1,2), (1,2,3), (1,5), (2,4)              [ 449940]
k = 15: (1,2,3), (1,2,3,4), (1,5), (2,3,4)        [ 525420]
k = 16: (1,2), (1,2,3), (1,5), (2,4,3)            [ 814070]
k = 17: (1,2,3), (1,2,3,4), (1,5), (2,3)          [1034670]
k = 18: (1,2)(3,4), (1,2,3,4), (1,2,4,3), (1,5)   [1208650]
k = 19: (1,2), (1,2,3), (1,2,3,4), (1,5)          [1199930]
k = 20: (1,2,3,4), (1,2,4,3), (1,3,2,4), (1,5)    [ 968760]
k = 21: (1,2)(3,4), (1,2,3,4), (1,5)(3,4), (2,3)  [ 527160]
k = 22: (1,2)(3,4), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5)           [ 242340]
k = 23: (1,2,3), (1,2,3,4), (1,5)(3,4), (2,4,3)   [  63240]
k = 24: (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5)                [   8310]
```

In brackets (added on Sep 18, 2013): the numbers of such 4-tuples of elements of ${\rm S}_5$.

**Added on Sep 18, 2013:** In case $n = 5$, at least for all
$k \in \{1, \dots, 5!\} \setminus \{117, 119\}$, suitable
5-tuples of group elements can be taken from ${\rm S}_6$ -- see [5tuples.txt](https://stefan-kohl.github.io/problems/5tuples.txt).

**Update (December 2013):** This question will appear as
Problem 18.50 in:

Kourovka Notebook: *Unsolved Problems in Group Theory*. Editors V. D.
  Mazurov, E. I. Khukhro. 18th Edition, Novosibirsk 2014.

Comment: In your example you have one group working for all k up to n!  Is this what you want or can the group change?

Comment: I think this doesn't make a difference -- if $G$ works for $k_1$ and $H$ works for $k_2$, then $G \times H$ works for both.

Comment: What about generalizing the problem: given any equivalence relation on $S_n$, can one find $G$ and the $g_i$ such that the map $S_n\to G,\: \sigma \mapsto g_{\sigma(1)}\cdot\ldots\cdot g_{\sigma(n)}$ identifies two permutations if and only if they are equivalent? Or is this trivially false?

Comment: Trivially false: if $abc=acb$, then $bca=cba$ as well.

Answer (score -1):

Pedantic answer: take $G$ to be a finitely presented group on $n+1$ generators $x_i$, with relations of the form $x_{n+1}^{-1}x_{\sigma(1)}...x_{\sigma(n)}$.  Here, $\sigma$ ranges over your favorite set of $n!-k+1$ permutations.  Take $g_i=x_i$.

If you really want a *finite* group $G$, then I don't know.

Comment: You ensure that at least $n!-k+1$ of the products of the 
$g_i$ are equal -- but can you also prove that the remaining $k-1$
are pairwise distinct? -- Your relations might force some of them
to be equal as well, or at least I don't see why they don't.



Comment: Hmm, I guess I don't either, now that you mention it.