# Numbers of distinct products obtained by permuting 3 factors

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and assume that there exist $a, b, c \in G$ such that
$abc$, $acb$, $bac$, $bca$, $cab$ and $cba$ are precisely 5 distinct elements
(i.e. that precisely two of the products are equal).

**Question 1:** Does it follow that there exist $d, e, f \in G$ such that
$def$, $dfe$, $edf$, $efd$, $fde$ and $fed$ are precisely 4 distinct elements?
And if not -- does the non-existence of such $d, e, f \in G$ at least imply
that $G$ is infinite?

*Remark:* When one replaces 5 by 6, the answer is *no*. -- The smallest group
which can be taken as an example here has order 54. It is
$$
  G_{54,8} :=
  \langle (1,4,7)(2,5,8)(3,6,9), (3,4,5)(6,8,7), (3,6)(4,7)(5,8) \rangle.
$$

**Question 2:** Let $G$ be as above, and assume further that there are no
$d, e, f \in G$ such that $def$, $dfe$, $edf$, $efd$, $fde$ and $fed$ are
pairwise distinct. If $G$ is finite, does it follow that the order of $G$
is a multiple of 5?

*Remark:* The groups of order up to 625 which fulfill the conditions have orders
20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 125, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 250, 260, 280, 
300, 320, 340, 360, 375, 380, 400, 420, 440, 460, 480, 500, 520, 540, 560,
580, 600, 620 and 625, respectively.

*Side note:* A related
[earlier question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123890/)
remains unsolved so far.

**Added on Aug 21, 2018:** Given a group $G$, put
$$
  {\rm P}_3(G) :=
  \left\{ |\{abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba\}| \ \big| \ a,b,c \in G \right\}.
$$
Then clearly we have ${\rm P}_3(G) = \{1\}$ if and only if $G$ is abelian.
Computational investigations further suggest that ${\rm P}_3(G)$ is always one
of $\{1\}$, $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, 
$\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$, $\{1,2,3,6\}$ and $\{1,2,6\}$ --
where $\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$ are all very
common, while $\{1,2,3,6\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ impose more-or-less
severe restrictions on the structure of the group.

Comment: Is there much literature on the three generated group with relation ABC=CBA ?  Gerhard "Most Other Cases Don't Work" Paseman, 2018.08.18.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Probably not much literature is needed: the group $<A,B,C|ABC=CBA>$ is isomorphic to $Z\ast Z^2$. Indeed writing $b=AB$ and $c=CA^{-1}$ reduces to the presentation $<A,b,c|bc=cb>$.

Comment: Suppose one computes a large but finite fragment of Z * Z * Z, with generators a,b, and c. (Or even the free semi group of words representing positive exponents.) The desired condition about five distinct elements  (thanks Ycor) implies two short words commute. Surely we can find in the large fragment three elements which generate exactly four more elements?  Just trying all words with at most 7 letters should be a feasible computation. If it fails, then you still have a partial result.  Gerhard "Not A Group Theory Programmer" Paseman, 2018.08.22.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Sorry, but I don't understand. -- Could you perhaps use somewhat more standard terminology and notation?

Comment: I am willing to explain, but I am confused. What part is nonstandard?  I am using the free product notation after Ycor.  The free semigroup which is the subset consisting of words with non negative exponents should make sense. Granted the terms are more common in semigroup theory, but should be clear.  Gerhard "Not Very Group Theory Conversant" Paseman, 2018.08.22.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Two words in a free group commute iff they generate a cyclic subgroup
(but that's hardly what you mean, is it?). And what is for you "a large but finite fragment"
-- is it perhaps a quotient, a subgroup, a coset, a ball, a sphere, any subset, or what else?

Comment: Apologies for my delayed response.  When I said above "the desired condition...implies two elements commute", I hoped you would infer that we would be taking quotients on the free group (but actually on the fragment which is a large finite subset of the free group). My belief was that inside such a fragment one could find the desired d e f of Question 1 (or representatives inside the quotient) and this would provide a proof.  Gerhard "Does This Make Things Clear?" Paseman, 2018.08.28.

Comment: @StefanKohl In the definition of $P_3(G)$ there is something wrong?! Please check it; you may do a swap ${\rm P}_3(G) :=
  \left\{ \ | \{abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba\} |  \ |\ a,b,c \in G \right\}$.

Comment: @StefanKohl It is known that if $6\not\in {\rm P}_3(G)$ then $G$ is metabelian and if $|G'|\leq 5$ then $6\not\in {\rm P}_3(G)$.

Comment: In addition to cardinalities, can you say what partitions (equivalence classes) occur of the six element set?  I can imagine the ones where everything commutes and where precisely two elements commute.  Gerhard "Maybe The Partition Types Matter" Paseman, 2018.08.29.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a group theorist, and this is not an answer. Maybe a group theorist can make it one, or at least take the idea further.

Suppose $abc=cab$ in the group G. Then the elements $c$ and $ab$ commute. Thus $a$, $ab$, and $c$ are three candidates for $d$, $e$, and $f$, and it can be shown that they produce at least three and at most four distinct products.  If the group they are in satisfies $abac$ is distinct from $caab$, then we have the required $d$, $e$, and $f$. Otherwise we have the additional derived relation $abaca=caaba$, so we have two other words commuting, in addition to the words $ab$ and $c$ commuting. If $G$ is finite, we may look for a contradiction by examining consequences of these two relations and show that they imply a forbidden relation such as $abc=cba$, which would give the result when $ab$ and $c$ commute (or $a$ and $bc$ commute).  Using Ycor's presentation of the group with relation $abc=cba$, we might be able to do something similar to the above for this case. If $G$ is not finite,  we might push on and consider $b$, $ab$, $c$ as candidates or $ca$, $aba$, and $b$ as candidates for $d$, $e$, and $f$.  I suspect that we will either hit on a good triple for $d$, $e$, $f$, or else the assumption and failure of two or three candidate sets will lead to a contradiction.

This is sort of like my idea in the comments (investigate certain quotients of the free group on 3 generators, or rather how the quotients look on a certain subset, except I am taking a much smaller subset and using a napkin and pen rather than a computer.)

Gerhard "The Wastebasket Will Come Later" Paseman, 2018.09.01.